# A complete transparent UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode5, alpha-transparency

I need a UITableView with no background color at all since I have the same Background image for
every page within my app. 
I know this was asked several times before, but none of the solutions posted here work for me.

I tried the

```
    .backgroundView = nil  
    .backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

thing for cells and tableview but the result was that I got a white background.
Some posts said that this is the new iOS7 standard.

I tried to set a color with an alpha value like this

```
    .backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
```

but that just gives me a black cell instead of a transparent one. So Aparently everything except the alpha value is applied here.

Also I got the problem that if you scroll the table over the "borders" there is still a white background. Is this the normal background of the tableview itself and would not be seen once the tableview did finally has an alpha value?

Oh, ofc appling an opacity-value from 0 in the inspector won't work either.

Am I missing something, is there a new way of doing this, is it even possible to have UITableViews that are complete transparent (excluding labels and images I've put in there of course)?

If that matters, I am currently using xCode 5.1.1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Alpha value should be 0 for a transparent cell, not 1

Comment: Oh I hate myself right now. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, it happens :) I think you can remove the question though, since it was a simple typo

Comment: Oh, I tried it right now, and while you are right, if I add a alphavalue of 0 its complete white again and if I add an alpha value of 0.6f as example, its black :/

Comment: Do you have any other view behind your tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to add that you'll also need to use clear color in the background of the tableview. Then you indeed got a 100% transparent table. Again, thank you =)